# Writing 5-dimensional dynamical system as Hamiltonian system

Tags: dynamical-systems, mathematical-physics

I've got a 5-dimensional continuous dynamical system, i.e.,

$$ 
\dot{x}(t)=f(x,y,z,u,w)\\
\dot{y}(t)=g(x,y,z,u,w)\\
\dot{z}(t)=h(x,y,z,u,w)\\
\dot{u}(t)=q(x,y,z,u,w)\\
\dot{w}(t)=p(x,y,z,u,w)
$$

Is there a systematic way of writing this system as a Hamiltonian system, without necessarily finding a conserved quantity dependent on all variables?  That method has proved itself to be quite difficult.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hamiltonian systems are very special, so you can't expect to be able to write an arbitrary system in Hamiltonian form.

Comment: @HansLundmark How would I determine whether this is possible or not?

Comment: For your example this should be obvious since any Hamiltonian system has an even dimension.

Comment: @Artem That's a fact I wasn't aware of.  I don't know much about Hamiltonian dynamics at all. Thanks!

Comment: @Artem: It's possible to define Hamiltonian systems on any Poisson manifold (and they can be odd-dimensional). But if you're talking about the usual symplectic case, then its even-dimensional, of course.

Comment: @HansLundmark In the case of an odd-dimensional system, how would obtain the Hamiltonian form?  I've been trying to find a conserved quantity, but I've been unsuccessful and am a bit lost.  Is there another way that I'm unaware of?

Comment: I don't think I know of any general methods, actually. If you want to write the system in a Hamiltonian form explicitly, you need to know the function $H(x,y,z,u,w)$, which is impossible if you don't know any constants of motion... Maybe you would be more successful if you posted your actual equations, and not just the general form. As it stands now, I don't think it's possible to give a good answer to your question.

Comment: @HansLundmark Thank you.  I'll mull it over and see what I can come up with before posting the exact system.